# LEA in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am learning x86 assembly, and have some troubles with the lea instruction.

```
 0x080486f7 <+21>:  lea    eax,[esp+0x18]
```

Can anybody explain what happens in this line? In my understanding, it takes the value at [esp+0x18] and interprets the value as an address, and puts the value of what is int the address into eax.

Answer (score 15):

Basically

```
mov eax, [esp+0x18]
```

means

```
mov eax, esp
add eax, 0x18
mov eax, [eax]
```

and in C that would look like

```
eax = *(unsigned int*)(esp + 0x18)
```

Meanwhile

```
lea eax, [esp+0x18]
```

means

```
mov eax, esp
add eax, 0x18
```

and in C that would look like

```
eax = esp + 0x18
```

Answer (score 1):

It stores `esp + 0x18` in `eax`. In other words, it's just addition. LEA is frequently used to perform basic arithmetic.

Comment: I'm convinced there is no abuse in asm.

Comment: OK, that was a joke, but I've changed "abused" to "used" :)